# Convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 3} \frac{4}{n^2 - 4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to solve the following series: $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{4}{n^2 - 4}$$ I'm not sure if the series starting at $3$ is throwing me off, but I think that I should use the limit comparison test. From Wolfram Alpha i get an answer $25/12$, but I get nothing close to that.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: You can use limit comparison test and compare your series with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @TomaszTarka clearly $\sum 1/n^2$ is not same as the problem given, why did you say that?

Comment: @MANMAID If $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to L\in(0, \infty)$ then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum b_n$ converges, it's obvious that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, and we can disregard finitely many terms because it doesn't change convergence.

Comment: Ok, @TomaszTarka , sorry, I thought you were saying that values will be same, btw you need to prove that $\sum 1/n^2$ is finite then, you can't assume that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $$\frac{4}{n^2-4} = \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2}.$$ Now telescope. In particular you can find a closed form for $\sum_{n=3}^{N} \left(\frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$ in terms of $N$. What happens as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Then one just simply solves for A and B like a partial fractions decomposition?

Comment: @ColeMurphy, I don't understand - I've already given the partial fraction decomposition. What is $A$ and $B$ and why are you trying to solve for them? Can you write out the first few terms of $\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n+3}$. Do you notice any special cancellations? What is the pattern.

Comment: I get it now.... thanks